# Expected Utility and $\log$

Tags: risk, modern-portfolio-theory, utility-theory

I've just started reading about expected utility and utility functions and have the following question.

$\textbf{Question:}$ An investor has an initial wealth of 100 and a utility function of the form:
\begin{align}
U(w) = \log(w)
\end{align}
What is their expected utility?

\begin{align}
\end{align}

Upon one of the slides I found on the web it states the following:

$\textbf{Calculating Expected Utility}$
1. When the choice variable $x$ is constant, then $E(U(x)) = U(x)$.
2. When the choice variable $x$ is a random variable, then $E(U(x))$ is driven by the PDF of $x$.
3. If $x$ has $k$ outcomes, each with probability $p_k$, then 
\begin{align}
E(U(x)) = \sum_{1}^{k} p_i U(x_i)
\end{align}

Since I'm told the initial wealth is 100 does this simply mean the expected utility is $E(U(100)) = \log(100)$?

Apologies if this is trivial - I'm just starting out.

All help is appreciated.
John

Comment: it seems a very strange question. Usually you are given the data as above plus a distribution of returns. In the absence of such a distribution, we only have $log(100).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strange question. Usually questions about expected utility involve some uncertainty about the future wealth of the investor. If there is no uncertainty in the outcome and the investor is not *doing* anything which might change his or her future wealth then the expectation of utility is a constant, that is $E[U(w)] = U(w)$.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the probability of gaining an amount  $x$ is $p$. Then the probability of losing an amount $y$ is $1-p$.

$E[U(W)]=pU(100+x)+(1-p)U(100-y)$

$=p\log{(100+x)}+(1-p)\log{(100-y)}$

$=p\log{(\frac{100+x}{100-y})}-\log{(100-y)}$

It should resemble something like that. I just gave you an overview, because I think a lot of details are missing in your question, never mind because you are new to this as you said.

In order to start a problem like this, you need a table

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
probabilty & \text{Gain} & \text{$W_0+x$} & \text{$U(W_0+x)$} \\
\hline
p & x & 100+x & \log({100+x}) \\
1-p & -y & 100-y & \log({100-y}) \\
\end{array}
$$

Your table could contain more probabilities depending on the question, but the sum of the probabilities must be equal to $1$.